# cant add value to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So Im reading in a RFID tag and wish to store the tag data into an sql database.

I cannot get it to store in the RFID field of my sql database without manually placing single quote marks around the tag data.

The RFID field is set to text in php myadmin.

How can I read the tag and have it automatically place single quote marks around the data??

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost" , "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxx");

$SQL = "INSERT INTO Track(RFID) VALUES (".$_GET["RFID"].")";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

echo "uploaded".$_GET["RFID"];
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not using string concatenation to apply parameters to your SQL statements. It makes your code vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](http://bobby-tables.com/). Use parameterized statements.

Comment: Your second image actually only shows the **description** of that column afaik. You need to do a select query to know for sure if there is content added.

Comment: Yes I know. Im just trying to get it to save the value to the database first. I will the sort out the security flaws. Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors, from MySQL or PHP?

Comment: As @GurV said, use parameterised queries (which means NOT using the mysql_* functions, which are dangerous and deprecated). Use PDO (or possibly the mysqli_* functions). In addition to preventing SQL injections, it will automatically fix the problem you are facing.

Comment: So when I write a value just containing numbers, say 45634 it s enters the value into the database, however when I try to write a value with letters and numbers, 45634rrty, it does not enter the values into the database. I need to manually put quote marks to enable it to enter the database ie '45634rrty'

Comment: ok ill change the code to use parameterised statements. Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO Track(RFID) VALUES ('".$_GET["RFID"]."')";
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the $SQL variable to include single quotes as follows: 
$SQL="INSERT INTO Track(RFID) VALUES('".$_GET["RFID"]."')";

You need to place the quote marks "in your SQL syntax" because you have specified the RFID field of Track table as text which falls into the string category(along with varchar() and the other text variants).

Also consider using mysqli_* functions as mysql_* functions are depreciated and only good to be used in PHP 4.x versions; use a newer version if you are using the 4.x ones.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You @hecate Yes that worked perfectly.
But I have taken into consideration what people have said about parameterized statements and will be changing my code to safegaurd against SQL injections. Still got a lot more learning to do!